# how to access the parent application property inside item renderer

Tags: apache-flex, custom-component, itemrenderer

I have a datagrid which has 3 columns in main application. In the third column I want to use the item renderer where I want to use hbox which has two components inside it. One is a button and one is a label. I also have a slider in the main application. I want to change the alpha of the button of itemrenderer from the main application file using the slider, where the datagrid is used. I can access the data provider properties inside the item renderer using data property. But how do I access the parent application properties. For this I tried to create custom datagrid and passed the value of slider using data binding. But could not access the property. In a list when I did the same thing, I could access the property using listData property of item renderer, but in case of datagrid I couldn't do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I access the parent application properties

Generally; I would recommend you don't.  An itemRenderer should be able to access all the properties it needs through the data element; which relates to the dataProvider.

It is a break in encapsulation to access properties of components that are higher up in the display hierarchy.

That said, there are a lot of ways to this.

To access the main application you can use [FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/FlexGlobals.html#topLevelApplication) to access the top level application.

You can store your slider value as a static variable and access it from the itemRenderer that way.

You could store the slider value in some data/model object and use a Dependency Injection Framework (Such as [Swiz](http://swizframework.org/) or [Robotlegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/examples/)) to inject that data/model object into your itemRenderer.

Comment: +1 for you shouldn't do this. I'd also add that you can create a ClassFactory and use it to provide the renderers with a reference to the slider or a bindable data object that reflects its value.

Comment: I have a blind spot on using a ClassFactory to send in properties.  Not sure why; I always forget that is there.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship how do I use the ClassFactory to access the properties of the parent application. By using listData property can we achieve the same goal? I had asked the same question few days with code. Its link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109821/how-to-access-the-listdata-property-in-item-renderer-for-datagrid-in-flex-4

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I think I got where I went wrong. I am using the renderer on the gridcolumn. In this case the parent of renderer is not the datagrid, but the gridcolumn. The value is passed to the datagrid not the gridcolumn. So it might be the reason why the renderer's listData is coming as null. In case of list, we pass the property to the list, so the renderer is able to access the listData property. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I don't know, as I feel that even using listdata is children meddling in the affairs of their parents, which I don't think is good practice. You may find that this solves your issue http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2008/09/extended-datagrid-with-stylefunction.html

Comment: In my case the renderer is in other file. I need to access the value of slider when the user drags it. Based on the current value of slider I want to set the logic in set data function. In this case the renderer is not interfering with the affairs of parent, but getting the value of some component to change the logic of renderer.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to access a outside property, you can use **outerDocument** inside of itemRenderer, for example:

//Code

```
        public var str:String = "Test";
        [Bindable] private var arr:Array = [
            {field:'ROW1'},
            {field:'ROW2'},
            {field:'ROW3'}                 
        ];
```

//MXML

```
<mx:DataGrid id="grid" width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{arr}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="field">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <mx:Label text="{data.field + ' ' + outerDocument.str}"/>
                </mx:Component> 
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

This [URL](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/05/09/using-a-slider-control-as-a-datagrid-column-item-renderer-in-flex/)   shows a good example of what I said. 
I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: In my case the renderer is in other file. I need to access the value of slider when the user drags it. Based on the current value of slider I want to set the logic in set data function.